# How to replace the %-encoded chars in a bunch of filenames by underscore using shell commands?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I downloaded lots of files, some of which containing invalid chars encoded to something like `%2C`, `%2F`...

I tried `rename 's/%[0-9][A-Z]/_/g *` and `rename 's/\%[0-9][A-Z]/_/g *` but they do nothing. (**Sorry, my fault. `rename` works. I input some typos or something related to fullwidth/halfwidth chars... ONZ.......... Plz vote to close this Q**)

For example, the filenames `file,1.pdf`, `file/2.pdf` ... are encoded as `file%2C1.pdf`, `file%2F2.pdf`. I want to rename them to `file_1.pdf`, `file_2.pdf`,...

Comment: It would be easier to see what the issue is if you [edit] your question to include some actual examples

Comment: @steeldriver good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
rename 's/%/_/g' *
```

First run it using `-n` option (dry run) to make sure everything is fine:

```
rename -n 's/%/_/g' *
```

To capture the number too:

```
rename -n 's/%[0-9]/_/g' *
```

---

or even use something like this to remove all characters except alpha-numeric ones:

```
$ rename -n 's/[^a-zA-z0-9]/_/g' *
rename(%SOME%2FFOR%, _SOME_2FFOR_)
rename(SOME%2FFOR, SOME_2FFOR)
rename(SOME%2FFOR%, SOME_2FFOR_)
```

Comment: looks @steeldriver's suggestion is good. Examples are necessary to clarify my Q.

Answer (score 0):

use the following script, copy the script and save it in `/bin` as `renamer.sh` then anytime you want to do any renamings on files of this type, use the simple command `renamer.sh #Input files#`;

```
#!/bin/bash

for input in $@;
    do 
        inputMod=$( echo "$input" | sed 's/\(%\)/\_/pg' );
        mv "$input" "$inputMod" &> /dev/null; 
        shift; 
    done;
```